# Junk number appearing after executing vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code that copies numbers (that doesn't have a color) from a range (here D3 to D30) and pastes it into F column staring from row 1 and does some percentile calculation.

Problem is, I noticed that a stray number "5" appears in F column in the first row even though there is no such number in my range D3 - D30.

```
   Sub TPNoRedpass50tablet()

     Dim cel As Range
     Dim Rng As Range
     Dim arr As Variant
     Dim i As Long
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       For Each cel In Sheets("TP").Range("TP!$D$3:$D$30")
         If cel.Font.Color = 0 Then
         If Rng Is Nothing Then
         Set Rng = cel
     Else
         Set Rng = Union(cel, Rng)
         End If
         End If
      Next cel
      ReDim arr(Rng.count - 1)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            For Each cel In Rng
               arr(i) = cel
               i = i + 1
      Next cel
     Sheets("TP").Range("F1").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
     Set Rng = Sheets("TP").Range("F1:I" & Sheets("TP").Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)
     Sheets("WBR").Range("AH101").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC(" & Rng.Address(, , , True) & ",50%)*24"
     Sheets("WBR").Range("AH101").Value = Sheets("WBR").Range("AH101").Value


      End If
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: You multiply by 24 for the percentile. Thus, do you have 0.21 in your range?

Comment: no..whatever the range is, I get the number "5" in the first row in "F". I'm not sure whether this a carry over or a mistake in my code

Comment: What is the value in Range("TP!$D$3)? The first row in F is transposed from there.

Comment: it's 6 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 (6,2,3,4, are colored numbers)..so in F, I get 5 (the junk) then 5 6 8 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Sub TPNoRedpass50tablet()

     Dim cel As Range
     Dim Rng As Range
     Dim arr As Variant
     Dim i As Long

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       For Each cel In Sheets("TP").Range("TP!$D$3:$D$30")
         If Rng Is Nothing Then
         Set Rng = cel       
         If cel.Font.Color = 0 Then
     Else
         Set Rng = Union(cel, Rng)
         End If
         End If
      Next cel
      ReDim arr(Rng.count - 1)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            For Each cel In Rng
               arr(i) = cel
               i = i + 1
      Next cel
     Sheets("TP").Range("F1").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
     Set Rng = Sheets("TP").Range("F1:I" & Sheets("TP").Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)
     Sheets("WBR").Range("AH101").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC(" & Rng.Address(, , , True) & ",50%)*24"
     Sheets("WBR").Range("AH101").Value = Sheets("WBR").Range("AH101").Value


      End If
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

The problem seems to be in the first for each loop. You have a union, which is carried out only the first time, when Rng is not set.